# Limited interface when flagging a question as better fitting for another Stack Exchange site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I try to flag a question as better fitting for another Stack Exchange site, I am only presented with a limited interface, that allows me to select from just a few other sites.

Namely, for example, from Stack Overflow, I can't send a question to for example [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour), or to software recommendations.

Do you have an idea how to improve on that?

Comment: Unfortunately as a group we're really bad at deciding whether a question is on-topic elsewhere and given a chance we try to migrate absolute rubbish. Options are limited to prevent us making a mess. Just close/flag the question as off-topic if it's off topic here. The OP can always ask it somewhere else if it's closed here.

Comment: Thanks, that really answers my question.